# Sending post request to Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Geolocation API for getting user's lat and lng coordinates, I read Google Maps Geolocation API 'docs, I used this code for my site:

```
  <?php
  $requestbody=array("considerIp"=>"true");
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, 
  CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?
  key=AIzaSyDsJyehD0QRujG5********");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$requestbody);
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  echo $result;
  ?>
```

I always get this error:

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "badContent", "message": "Unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3fbf377f9ad74da3" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3fbf377f9ad74da3" } }

In docs Google said `considerIp=true` means I will receive IP location when WiFi station or cellphone connection isn't available, but I don't know why I get this error.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Comment: According to the docs you should set content-type to application/json... it seems your error is complaining about that.